# Not Found: /available.html "GET /available.html HTTP/1.1" 404 2319

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am trying to create a path for the second function on my views page so I can create a buyers page and connect it to the database, but I am having difficulties finding help online for this specific problem so if someone could help and also show me a good series to watch to help with the creation of this private server ran website.

```
Page not found (404)
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[01/Jun/2020 23:18:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2310
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/available.html
Using the URLconf defined in TJWEXOTICS.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin
[name='home-page']
[name='available-page']
The current path, available.html, didn't match any of these.
```

it says this after i run the server and then try to go to the pythons page:

> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to >False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

heres the urls.py paths:

```
    from django.urls import path

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
         path(r'', views.title, name='home-page'),
         path(r'', views.available, name='available-page')
    ]
```

Here is the views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Snake

# Create your views here.


def title(request):
    return render(request, 'TJW/Homepage.html')


def available(request):

    # return render(request, 'TJW/available.html')

    all_snakes = Snake.objects.all()
    html = 'TJW/available.html'
    for snake in all_snakes:
        path = '/TJW/' + str(Snake.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href= "' + path + '" >' + Snake.snake_mutation + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a path:

```
path('available/', views.available, name='available-page')
```

And, go the the path to check if available view is working or not. Now, your available page will look like. `http://localhost:8000/available/`

Comment: `available.html` differs from `available/`.

Comment: Yes. I was saying to add the route as available to have easily passed to ```available.html```